# Can two women travel with non mahram?

Tags: women, non-mahram, travelling, mahram

A woman can't travel with a non mahram (alone), but can two women (together) travel with a non mahram?

Comment: If one can’t, what makes two or three or four able to?!

Comment: @Epistemophile.Bibliophile well two women could resolve the issue of being alone with a foreigner as accepted by some scholars. Further there is the concept of safe company in which a group of women can go to hajj in company of one man.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I searched, it is not haram for several women to travel with a non-mahram if it does not have a corruptor. But why is it really difficult for a woman to travel with a non-mahram? . The fact that two women travel with a non-mahram still carries the risk of being close to sin. It is like asking if I can play with fireworks ?? Can I light a fire in the corner of my room on the floor ??

https://hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/2399/